# Space used by tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Does this procedure accurately show the space used in a db? I'm doubting the results.

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100)    --For storing values in the cursor

--Cursor to get the name of all user tables from the sysobjects listing
DECLARE tableCursor CURSOR
FOR 
select [name]
from dbo.sysobjects 
where  OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1
FOR READ ONLY

--A procedure level temp table to store the results
CREATE TABLE #TempTable
(
    tableName varchar(100),
    numberofRows varchar(100),
    reservedSize varchar(50),
    dataSize varchar(50),
    indexSize varchar(50),
    unusedSize varchar(50)
)

--Open the cursor
OPEN tableCursor

--Get the first table name from the cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM tableCursor INTO @TableName

--Loop until the cursor was not able to fetch
WHILE (@@Fetch_Status >= 0)
BEGIN
    --Dump the results of the sp_spaceused query to the temp table
    INSERT  #TempTable
        EXEC sp_spaceused @TableName

    --Get the next table name
    FETCH NEXT FROM tableCursor INTO @TableName
END

--Get rid of the cursor
CLOSE tableCursor
DEALLOCATE tableCursor

--Select all records so we can use the reults
SELECT * 
FROM #TempTable order BY tablename

--Final cleanup!
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

Sorry about the formating of this post. StackO sure is buggy - no formatting toolbar today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code gives a table-by-table view of space used.  You can also just run `sp_spaceused` without params to get an overview of the size of the whole database.  What causes you to doubt the results?

Comment: Thanks for the tip that the stored proc accepts table name as a param.  The  proc's output match the output from above. I doubted it because the sum of the table space used exceeded the db size after converting KB to MB.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to consider using one of the [system's dynamic views / functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188754.aspx)

For example, consider this simple query using [sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188917.aspx) to return much more detailed information on the pages used for heaps clustered and non-clustered indexes:

```
select * from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats ( 
    DEFAULT 
  , DEFAULT 
  , DEFAULT 
  , DEFAULT 
  , 'DETAILED'
)
```